# Creating Java Application using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: java, visual-studio

Is it possible to create a **Java** application using **Visual Studio** 2013?

Because I don't like using NetBeans or Eclipse and I prefer using Visual Studio over those SDKs.

Thanks.

Comment: To be open, 
VS 2013 doesn't support Java and some plugins are there for syntax highlighting but nothing makes VS to work for Java like C#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754713/using-java-with-microsoft-visual-studio-2012?rq=1

Comment: Why insist using Visual Studio, just because you "don't like using .netbeans or Eclipse" ? Doesn't sound like making sense.

Comment: I don't like NetBeans or Eclipse ether. [IDEA is pretty good](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (I don't even write C# without the IntelliJ ReSharper addin!) Anyway, [J++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B)/J# (the Microsoft form of "Java" and transitory path) [has been removed since VS2008 (since 2005 for J++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xsxf8e2(v=vs.90).aspx) so .. not supported.

Comment: I would like to have Java on Visual Studio, for two reasons, it IS a strong IDE, and Eclipse fails way too much.

Answer (score 5):

you cannot create java programs from Visual Studio 2013. you have to use intelliJ or Eclipse or Netbeans or something like that. Eclipse is a very good IDE and there are many useful tools you can add to Eclipse.

Update: from @kamran's comment below, came through [this link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93). Though you cannot expect it to function like a fully equipped IDE it is promising. It is an extension to the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: How about http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93

Comment: @KamranShahid It is not a fully equipped IDE ideal for java development.. you can see from the description that, it is a very basic extension that helps in syntax highlighting and braces matching. You cannot expect this extension to make visual studio to function as it would in a c# program (intellisense, debugging etc) But it is looking promising. Will update my answer on this. Thx.. :)