# How to set up visual studio 2013 for Java

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide

Visual Stdio (haha) seems like an awesome and free dev tool to use since it is pretty versatile. I am currently learning java, and intend to learn C++ and Unity5, both of which can be developed for in VS. My question is, how do I set up VS for Java? Is it as simple as installing a plugin, or is there something else I've got to do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Wait, posted the wrong link. Try this one: [Creating Java Application using Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996660/creating-java-application-using-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Visual Studio for Java unless you install a plug in like https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93
However the plugin might not be as consistent as a complete Java IDE