# Is there any way to program Java on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio Community 2015, and have used it extensively, and it is one of my favorite IDEs ever. Is there any way to code Java with it? Such as an extension like Python tools for Visual Studio? Thanks in advance.
Yes, but this is with *2015*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Java with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754713/using-java-with-microsoft-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Language Support](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93) extension provides basic features for the Java programming language. Current editing features include:

- Syntax highlighting and brace matching
- Outlining support for quickly collapsing classes and functions
- Dropdown bars listing classes, enums, interfaces, fields, and methods within the current document

Comment: Is there an extension for Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1):

How to add an Java extension for Visual Studio 2015:

1. Tools -> Extensions and Updates
2. Left column, click on "Online" to expand
3. Right column, in the searching box "Search Visual Studion Gallery (Ctrl+E)", type: Java Language Support" (kinda case sensitive)
4. Download the extension which is graphically shaped as cup of coffee!
5. Restart Visual Studio

To make sure you are on the track, try to create a new java project:

1. File -> New Project
2. Left column for the installed template, you should now observe Java
3. Console application, give it a name and a location
4. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. I'm not a seasoned programmer, but I usually only get in Visual when doing C++, I would recommend Netbeans or Eclipse for Java SE. I've never worked with the other editions.